# How to forbid specific files through file permissions?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a sendmessage.php file and other similar files that send email. I would like to forbid direct visit to these files, keep them workable, but I do not know why.

How to do this?

This is how I use them

```
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'sendmessage-contact.php',
                data: $("#contact").serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    if(data == "true") {
                        $("#send").fadeOut("fast", function(){
                            $(this).before("<p><strong style='color:#D60096'></strong></p>");
                            setTimeout("$.fancybox.close()", 3000);
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: You call `sendmessage-contact.php` via the client (via JS) but you want to block it too from the client? Please think a bit about it

Comment: You don't know why you want to prevent access to these files?

Answer (score 2):

performing a simple `deny form all` in your case may not fit your requirements, so I make another suggestion:

Instead, you should generate a random hashed string on page load and write it to a session:

```
session_start();
//$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] is pretty much pointless, just illustrating redundancy here, may not work for you so remove as desired
if(isset($_POST['hash_key']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']):
    if(isset($_SESSION['hash_key']) && $_POST['hash_key'] === $_SESSION['hash_key']):
        //call your function to process this
        return myFunction($_POST['contact']);
    else:
        //no session key, deny them
        header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    endif;
elseif(!isset($_POST['hash_key']) && !isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])):
    //not trying to post, not trying to send ajax, generate a new hash key
    $_SESSION['hash_key'] = md5(uniqid(rand( ), true)); 
endif;
```

Now later in the page when you generate your HTML, you need to make a hidden input carrying this value.

```
<input type="hidden" id="hash_key" name="hash_key" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['hash_key'];?>"/>
```

Now you can pass this value to the server in your ajax function:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'sendmessage-contact.php',
    data: {
        'contact' : $("#contact").serialize(),
        'hash_key' : $("#hash_key").val()
    },
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Now if bots to try to spam your script it won't matter because they'll get a 403 forbidden error as they're not going to be able to match the uniquely generated string that we create for our `$_SESSION['hash_key']`.

**Disclaimer**

Please under no circumstances actually use `md5(uniqid(rand( ), true))`. I've simply provided this for brevity and it is NOT a fully secure method.

**Edit**

Overly verbose. simplified.

Comment: Thank you for this, I am trying it. However I can not get the data: {} part working. I uploaded more of my code if it helps.

Comment: @Karoumpas Please see the above edit.